# header("HTTP/1.1 200 $status_message") took more than 5 second to run on local host. AM I doing something wrong?

Tags: php

My code is given below. Its a simple rest api. When url is called from another page, it take 5 seconds to give back the response because of header("HTTP/1.1"). I am running it on localhost.

```
    <?php
    header("Content_type:application/json");
    if (!empty($_GET['name'])) {
        $name=$_GET['name'];
        $price=get_price($name);
        if (!empty($price)) {
            response('200','book found',$price);
        } else {
            response('200','book not found',null);
        }

    } else {
        response('400','invalid request',null);
    }

    function response($status,$status_message,$data){
        header("HTTP/1.1 $status,$status_message");//this line take more than 5 seconds to run
        $result['status']=$status;
        $result['status_message']=$status_message;
        $result['data']=$data;
        echo json_encode($result);
    }
    function get_price($name){
        $book=[
            'a'=>100,
            'b'=>200,
            'c'=>300

            ];
            foreach ($book as $key => $value) {
                if ($key==$name) {
                    return $value;
                    break;
                }
            }
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: How exactly did you figure out it was that line?

Comment: @deceze I ran it once with that line and once without and he's definitely right about it.

Comment: Maybe because the syntax for that header is incorrect? There's not supposed to be a `,` in there.

Comment: removed the , doesn't help.

Comment: @MrLore That still doesn't answer the question as to why the thought is this line takes 5 seconds.  This is probably going to come down to buffering somewhere.

Comment: @Brad How does it not? With the line = 5 seconds, without the line = 0 seconds. It's the request/response mismatched protocol problem I outlined below.

Comment: @MrLore To be clear, my point is that `header()` isn't taking 5 seconds to execute... it is causing a side effect that makes the script appear to take 5 seconds to execute as a whole.

Comment: Also it's `Content-Type` not `Content_type`.